# node.js https module "unable to determine the domain name"

Tags: node.js, https

I am getting

> unable to determine the domain name

error when using `https.get` in node.js application.

My code is below:

```
const options = {
                    hostname: hostname,
                    port: 443,
                    path: remotePDFFilePath,
                    method: 'GET'
                };
https.get(hostname + remotePDFFilePath, res => {
    res.setEncoding("base64");
    let body = "";
    res.on("data", data => {
        body += data;
    });
    res.on("end", () => {
        callback(null, {
            status: 1,
            response: body.toString('base64')
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried searching Google and StackOverflow but did not find any relevant information. I tried changing `https` module with `http` but got he same error.

The value for `hostname` is "*subdomain.domain.org*" and the value for `remotePDFFilePath` is "*/January Folder/Last, First DocID.pdf*".

Comment: Could you inspect the values of `hostname` and `remotePDFFilePath` in the debugger, or log those into the console and post the value here?

Comment: @RamizWachtler I have edited and updated my question with the values.

Comment: Could you try `https.get(options, res => {...})` instead of `https.get(hostname + remotePDFFilePath, res => {...})`

Comment: Although not directly an answer to my question, as I am already using TRY CATCH, but a relevant one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933229/why-is-this-basic-node-js-error-handling-not-working?rq=1

Comment: @RamizWachtler interestingly, following your latest suggestion fixed my issue. Now https is connecting. I wonder what could have been the logic behind that.

Comment: I think the way you tried to use `https.get(...)` is not quite correct. It accepts a string or a URL object as param, but the string is probably only valid as a standalone domain (that means, without any path). For the path, you've the option `path`.